# Where does CEPH store device metrics for each device? [ceph reef]

Tags: ceph

I just deployed my first ceph cluster and have been trying multiple things so far.

Though, I couldn't understand how ceph store metric for the devices.

I can easily access those through:

```
# ceph device get-health-metrics --help
```

Even though it doesn't seem obvious. I've been looking for `device_health_metrics` pool, though, that seems to be renamed to `.mgr` in newer releases ([blog post](https://ceph.io/en/news/blog/2022/v17-2-0-quincy-released/)).

The thing that is making me confused is that manager module `devicehealth` is targetting a pool that doesn't exist: `device_health_metrics` and I am still able to retrieve metrics without errors.

[image: device health module]

I am also able to run the following without errors:

- `ceph device scrape-health-metrics`
- `ceph device scrape-daemon-health-metrics osd.1`

Mind sharing your thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is in [documentation](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/mgr/administrator/#module-pool) for manager modules.

> Prior to Quincy, the devicehealth module created a device_health_metrics pool to store device SMART statistics. With Quincy, this pool is automatically renamed to be the common manager module pool.